# Unable to input password to create account in Xcode's iphone simulator

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase

I'm trying to simply build functionality for a user to open the app and enter email and a password to create an account. I'm using Firebase.

In the simulator, everything works like it should: The user opens the app, taps create account, enters email, but for password, once I type the first letter, the input bar freezes and has a yellow backdrop with text that reads "strong password." When I hit save, I get a message in the simulator, "Strong passwords have at least six characters and a mix of letters and numbers." It doesn't create the account.

In Xcode the message is: "Cannot show Automatic Strong Passwords for app. . . due to error: iCloud Keychain is disabled."

```
    // Get the default auth UI object
    
    let authUI = FUIAuth.defaultAuthUI()
    
    guard authUI != nil else {
        return
    }
    
    // Set ourselves as delegate and spec sign-in options
    
    authUI?.delegate = self
    authUI?.providers = [FUIEmailAuth()]
    
    // Get a reference to the Auth UI view controller
    
    let authViewController = authUI!.authViewController()
    
    // Show it
    
    present(authViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

I'm new to the game, so if I accidentally left out important information, let me know. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Not a fix but a work around. If you have this problem you can trigger a menu to choose your own password and that stops the Strong password autofill.

To trigger the menu put the focus in another (non-password) field and then put the focus back into the password field. Repeat this step two or three times and then a menu will show up from the operating system that will let you choose your own password.[image]